# ADsOpenObject - Connect to rootDSE of another domain in same network

Tags: visual-c++, active-directory, ldap

I need to connect to the rootDSE of another domain in the same network.I referred the solution found in this [Microsoft Forum Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/51480dc4-ee6d-41c9-af74-749d607c2022/unable-to-search-the-user-in-a-specific-domain?prof=required).  I used the following code to establish connection.

```
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://DC1.domain.com/rootDSE",
    L"admin",
    L"password",
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IADs,
    (void**)&pObject);

if(!SUCCEEDED(hr)){
    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    std::wcout<<errMsg<<L"\n";
}
```

I'm unable to connect to the rootDSE, The Error message(errMsg):

> The server is not operational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished connecting to rootDSE of another Domain in same network by using the following LDAP patter:

```
"LDAP://win2k3/rootDSE"
```

Note: NETBIOS Name of my DC is win2k3. win2k3 belongs to another domain, but is in the same network as my computer.

```
IADs *pObject;
HRESULT hr;
CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://<DC-NETBIOS>/rootDSE",
    username,
    password,
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IADs,
    (void**)&pObject);

if (hr == S_OK) printf("\nBind to rootDSE success\n");
else {
    _com_error err(hr);
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();
    std::wcout << L"Hresult: " << errMsg << L"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't reach the domain controller. Test your network connectivity to the server.

AD can use any one of 4 ports:

- 389: LDAP (unencrypted) This is the default if you don't specify anything
- 636: LDAP over SSL (encrypted)
- 3268: Global catalog (your whole forest)
- 3269: Global catalog over SSL

You can test network connectivity from PowerShell:

```
(new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect("DC1.domain.com", 389)
```

No output means success. If it fails, it will tell you. If port 389 doesn't work, try the others. If one of the others works, you can specify that in your LDAP path: `"LDAP://DC1.domain.com:3268/rootDSE"`